# How to insert Video element in my Ubuntu application?

Tags: application-development, qt, qml, ubuntu-sdk, software-installation

I saw on some sites that you can insert videos with the Video element by importing Qt 4.7 and QtMultimediaKit 1.1 . But I have an error by compiling the project (it's a tabbed touch UI project):

```
(file path)/Presentation1.qml:44 Type BackButtonTab unavailable
(file path)/ui/BackButtonTab.qml:4 module "Qt" is not installed
(file path)/ui/BackButtonTab.qml:5 module "QtMultimediaKit" is not installed
(file path)/ui/BackButtonTab.qml:4 module "Qt" is not installed
(file path)ui/BackButtonTab.qml:5 module "QtMultimediaKit" is not installed

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlscene exited with code 255
```

I thought about adding Qt 4.7 and QtMultimediaKit 1.1 in the .qmlproject but it doesn't change anything

The message tells me that I have to install QtMultimediaKit and Qt, but I don't know how to do it. (I've got the same problem with 3D elements by importing Qt3D 1.0 or Qt.labs.threed 1.0 -> what's the difference between Qt3D 1.0 and Qt.labs.threed 1.0 ?)

I'm using Qt Creator 2.8.1 based on Qt 5.0.2 (GCC 4.7.3, 64 bit) built on Sep 16 2013 at 12:02:18 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install the "QtMultimediaKit" you only need to install the `libqtmultimediakit1` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libqtmultimediakit1
```

Hopefully, it will install the Qt module that you are missing too.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! I just had to add: "import QtMultimedia 5.0" (none of QtMultimediaKit 1.1 or Qt 4.7) after installing libqtmultimediakit1 like you said! And it works very well!