# Qt QML modules, how to import them and know what to import & QtMultimediaKit 1.0

Tags: qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

In the last question, ([How to insert Video element in my Ubuntu application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390766/how-to-insert-video-element-in-my-ubuntu-application)) I thought that I could create the Video element with the QtMultimediaKit1 . But I tried to import QtMultimediaKit 1.0 and it doesn't worked!
I eventually found out that I could import it with `import QtMultimedia 5.0`.

Although it was working, I managed to find it in the Software Center. I noticed that the modules started with "libqt...". And there it is! Or there THEY are! Because I found out that the installed module (QtMultimediaKit 1.0) and the imported one (QtMultimedia 5.0) are two different things!

[image: QtMultimediaKit 1.0]

not the same as

[image: QtMultimedia 5.0]

The compiling error is the same as in the last question when I use QtMultimediaKit 1.0.

**What are the differences between both of them?**

**Why wont the QtMultimediaKit 1.0 work?**

I saw some documentation about it :

- These are for C++, aren't they?

  - http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qtmobility/multimedia.html?tab=3&q=QtMultimediaKit&sp=all
  - http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-mobility-snapshot/multimedia.html
- here, they are talking about QML (and ... QtMultimediaKit 1.1 ??!!)

  - http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qtmobility/qml-video.html?tab=3&q=QtMultimediaKit&sp=all

I tried with QtMultimediaKit 1.**1** instead of 1.**0** but it's the same problem:

```
(file path)/ConfigureButtonTab.qml:4 module "QtMultimediaKit" is not installed

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlscene exited with code 255
```

I'm still under 13.10 and with Qt Creator 2.8.1 based on Qt 5.0.2 (GCC 4.7.3, 64 bit) built on Sep 16 2013 at 12:02:18.

P.S.: **A little additionnal question: how can I know what to install to have the right module?** For instance, the 3D module: I have something installed but I do not know what to import and if it's realy the right module (the installed-one is: Qt 3D module: libqt53d5)

Thank you! : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Ubuntu Touch uses Qt 5 and `qtmultimediakit` is an older Qt Mobility module. See [this quote from Qt's website](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/changes.html):

> The Qt Multimedia module in Qt 5 combines (and replaces) two older modules, namely the Qt Multimedia module from Qt 4.x, and Qt Multimedia Kit module from Qt Mobility. Existing code that uses Qt Multimedia from Qt 4 can be ported with minimal effort, but porting code that uses Qt Multimedia Kit may be a more involved process. The changed features section highlights changes relevant to porting.

In other words, the Qt Multimedia module in Qt 5 is the successor to QtMultimediaKit. Since Ubuntu Touch only uses Qt 5 I don't think QtMultimediaKit would work.

The reason your import didn't work was because the QtMultiMediaKit files are stored in `/usr/lib/<architecture>/` while the SDK only looks in the `qt5` folder of `/usr/lib/<architecture>/`.

Long story short, using the Qt 5 Multimedia Module is the right way of doing it!

Comment: Thank you! Just an additionnal question about the end. How to import the 3D module (Is it a Qt4/5 problem too?)? And how to improt it (Should I change a path, so that the SDK looks in /usr/lib/<architecture>/)?

Comment: @tuxtoriel I don't know. That really should be a separate question.